# GCM token is not generated using Parse-android-sdk

Tags: parse-platform

As per docs : http://parseplatform.org/docs/android/guide/#setting-up-push

```
// Save the current Installation to Parse.
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

Above line is being executed upon sign in. Then on parse dashboard new entry appears under "Installation" class. But device-token is showing "undefined" on parse dashboard.

With this case every time new entry is created on parse dashboard upon sign in but all entries missing device token.

I have done GCM push setup as per docs. Please advise.

Comment: Is that user successfully logged in?

Comment: Yes @Cliffordwh. There was a issue with AndroidManifest permission. It is Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i was making mistake by putting wrong application package in permission tags of AndroidManifest.xml file

Now app is generating token after adding correct package name in Permission tags. Application package name is : com.app.myapp and Below is the working piece of code now:

```
<!--
    IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
    to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
    -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.app.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.app.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```